# Extract data from json and save it to text file using python

Tags: python, xml, json

This is my first question here so to get started i want to write a code to extract some text from a json file from imdb then store the data into a text file from the command line with some arguments the source file.the plan is to construct the url from the title given with some parameters implemented on mymovieapi restapi (a request ) retrieve the answer, parse the json and then save the data to a txt file.I ve done the part of constructing the url and then with the help and url lib encode(parameters).In addition I am not so sure with format to retrieve json (json.loads) or xml (xml.dom.minidom)?I am a new programmer and trying to implement all this but am stuck .

Comment: Since you mention you've already solved half the problem, you should post your current code so we can pick up from there

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. One unique aspect of StackOverflow is that all of our conversations begin with a question. Your have adequately described your situation, but you are missing that key element: the question. Please consider the advice from the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit your post to include a specific question.

Comment: thanks guys i solved it .should i post it but its not the best quality code out there!!!